# Serialize or Use a Separate Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having a City model and every city has combat units specified in the model CombatUnit. I initially create a has many through city_combat_units association, but i am not too sure if this is really the best way to go.

Since there are 10 different types of combat units, there's lots of duplication like :

```
(city_id, combat_unit_id, number) => (1,1,10)
(city_id, combat_unit_id, number) => (1,2,4)
(city_id, combat_unit_id, number) => (1,3,9)
```

You get the idea. So, i am wondering. Could it be better to make it so that a City has one combat_units_list where the list attribute is just a serialized hash that contains the names and numbers of the units ?

Would it be a good idea? Would it be versatile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I'd suggest you stick with your current model, it allows for easier manipulation of the relationship between your city and your combat units. Yes, you'll have some minor duplication of ids, but it's a lot cleaner than having the serialized list as you proposed.

I can also picture some scenarios where having the relationship mapped in a table would help, for instance, if you need to know how many cities have 10 combat units of type 2, answering this question with your current setup it's pretty straight forward, the other solution implies parsing the list for every city and then finding the coming up with some algorithm to answer the question.

You'll be saving some bytes on your database, but loading your code with querying logic (which should be the responsability of your db engine if you ask me).

So, to summarize, unless your **really** need the serialization option for some kind of strange optimization, I'd suggest sticking with your table.

Answer (score 1):

Serialized attributes may be faster to fetch, but they are much slower to alter. Adding an entry to a large list will require re-writing the entire list with the new entry appended. They also suffer from race conditions where one update might be over-written by another. A join model is almost always the most reliable way to do this.

If you want the performance of a serialized list, make it a cache of the join records so that if it does become corrupted you can rebuild it. Creating a join model is usually trivial and it can easily accommodate metadata like `number` in your example.